# How to find intercepts of a function

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

I have two functions that are $y=\sin x$ and $y=\sin x + 0.5\cos 2x$ and am required to find the intercepts. I let them both equal each other so I was left with $\sin x = \sin x + 0.5\cos 2x$. I thought an easy way would be to subtract the $\sin x$'s from each other and take the inverse cos of 0 but that didn't appear right when I graphed it. Can someone help please?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

The equations are stated as follows:

$$y=sinx \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ y=sinx+0.5cos(2x)$$

The solution (point of intersection between both equations), can be determined via equality. Thus we have:

$$sinx=sinx+0.5cos(2x)\implies0.5cos(2x)=0\implies cos(2x)=0$$

Note $cos(x)=0\iff x=\frac {\pi}{2}\pm n\pi$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Thus: $cos(2x)=0\iff x=\frac {\pi}{4}\pm n\frac {\pi}{2}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Why? Well the solutions to $cos(2x)=0$ are simply determined by taking the solutions of $cos(x)=0$ and dividing by $2$.

For a intercept of the form $(x,y)$ in 2-dimension, and knowing all the $x$ values for each solution/intercept, can you determine the corresponding $y$ values?

Comment: Yes I can just substitute the x values into the formulas. Thank you so much

Comment: No problem, anytime! :)